# IoT device does not appear in the network

Tags: security, switch

I'm using a simple Linux-base IoT device (Red Pitaya board) to run my remote monitoring solution on a industrial network based on a advanced manageable switch (model AT-XS916MXT, by Allied Telesis).

I am basically connecting the device and a computer, over wired connections, ti this switch, but I can't ping the device from my computer. For simplicity, I have determine static IPs for both devices. Here are the settings:

IoT: 192.168.51.10/24 PC: 192.168.51.12/24 Gateway: 192.168.51.1

More information: - The IoT device's current OS and ecosystem versions are Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS and 0.97, respectively. - My computer is a PC (notebook) running windows 7. - When I replace the IoT device for a secondary Windows-based PC, it is possible to ping it from the main PC (same static IP and default gateway used for the IoT device) - A direct wired-connection between the main PC and the IoT device works normally.

Unfortunately, I have restricted access to this switch and I may not be able to provide more details do its settings.

But given that it works for most network devices (mostly Linux/Windows computers), I believe there should be some service or behavior on the IoT device that is triggering some security policy on the switch...

... is that assumption possible? What possible policies this switch have that could be triggering this?

Answer (score 1):

It is quite possible that the switch disrupts the connection due to configuration. However, it is impossible to say what is configured without seeing the configuration.

What you can check:

1. Do the link LEDs come on when plugging the IoT device? The switch port may be fixed to MDI-X and when the device's NIC also uses (only) MDI-X the link will not come up.
2. Can you ping the device when you connect it directly to a PC NIC?
3. When the device doesn't respond to ping, can you see the MAC address in the local ARP cache (`arp -a` in Windows)?

Comment: 1) The device's NIC does support auto MDI/MDI-X (I have tested). 2) A direct connection PC <-> Device does work. 3) Did not test this yet I will check.